# Getting information throw url using ajax

Tags: php, jquery

I want to ask you about ajax and php using jQuery Lib. Basically, I have two files, one the actual file message.php?id=23 23 refers to the member's ID. I do want to do refresh every 5 seconds.

I did it well, but I didn't know how to send the member's ID, to get some informations from the Database.

This is the code I have:

```
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script> 

<script> 
 $(document).ready(function() { 
      $(".Refresh").load('postnm.php'); 
   var refreshId = setInterval(function() { 
      $(".Refresh").load('postnm.php'); 
   }, 5000); 
   $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); 
}); 
</script>
```

So the idea is to send the id just like `$_GET['id']` in PHP.

Comment: Have you tried `$(".Refresh").load('postnm.php?id=23');`?

Comment: 23 is just exemple , it can be any number

Comment: Have you tried `$(".Refresh").load('postnm.php?id='+id);` where `id` is the number?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the script is being written to the browser by PHP, just use PHP to put the ID into your JS:

```
<script>
    var id = <?php echo $member_id?>;
```

And then:

```
   $(document).ready(function() { 
        $(".Refresh").load('postnm.php?id=' + id); 
     var refreshId = setInterval(function() { 
        $(".Refresh").load('postnm.php?id=' + id); 
     }, 5000); 
     $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); 
  });
</script>
```